# SQL Query based on value of another table

Tags: sql

Suppose That I have Table A and Table B as follow. How would I get my expected outcome ? The filtering should be dynamically based on values in Table A as follow

```
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE
(Start = 'A' AND End = 'B')
OR (Start = 'C' AND End = 'D')
OR (Start = 'B' AND End = 'A')
```

**Table A**

```
Start End
A     B
C     D
B     A
```

**Table B**

```
ID Start End  Date
1  A     B    2021-01-01
2  A     B    2021-01-01
3  C     D    2021-01-01
4  B     A    2021-01-01
5  C     D    2021-01-01
6  E     A    2021-01-01
6  D     C    2021-01-01
```

**Expected Result**

```
ID Start End  Date
1  A     B    2021-01-01
2  A     B    2021-01-01
3  C     D    2021-01-01
4  B     A    2021-01-01
5  C     D    2021-01-01
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems a simple join is all that is required?

```
select *
from TableB B
inner join TableA A on
    A.Start = B.Start
    and A.End = B.End
```